# Dealing with a Pyspark schema where data could be absent (dtype: float / DoubleType()) or present (dtype: str / StringType()), not both

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

How can I deal with a schema where the data could or not be included in the `dataframe` but needs to be always there defined?

My data is previously manipulated with Pandas, where I do all the parsing and cleaning, later I require of the Pyspark schema to import it to the `datalake`. In Pandas I could consider to include the column and to fill it with a string, something like

`pd_df['col_A'] = pd_df['col_A'].fillna('NotProvided')`

just to give an example. Is there a smarter solution?

If this data is **not included** then I would have by default `NaN` values which are `dtype: float`, then in the schema need to be defined as `DoubleType()`, but when the data **is present** then it would be defined as `StringType()`. This is under the scenario where my data would be **indeed strings**. In a scenario **only with numbers**, `DoubleType()` works.

As far as I know, there is not data type that manages both.

Example schema:

```
schema = StructType([
    StructField("col_A", StringType(), False),
    StructField("col_B", DoubleType(), True),
    StructField("col_C", StringType(), False),
    StructField("col_D", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("col_F", StringType(), False)
])
```